# GitHub Actions expression functions: string manipulation?

Tags: github-actions

In a GitHub Actions workflow definition file, there's [a set of built-in functions that you can use in expressions](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#functions).

For example: `${{ toJson(github) }}`

Are there any string manipulation functions that can be used in an expression, such as `toLowerCase`?

The documentation page doesn't mention any. However, I'm wondering if Github uses some sort of standard templating / expression eval library under the hood which has provides a larger set of functions out of the box.

Comment: I've exactly the same question, did you got an answer somewhere ?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I usually work around this with Bash scripts.

Answer (score 9):

Impossible. [GitHub expressions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions) doesn't allow string modification, only concatenation.

You could do almost the same with a custom step in a build job, but this means that you won't be able to use that variable everywhere (for example "processed" environment name is out of the question).

```yaml
env:
  UPPERCASE_VAR: "HELLO"
steps:
  - id: toLowerCase
    run: INPUT=${{ env.UPPERCASE_VAR }} echo "::set-output name=lowerCaseValue::${INPUT,,}"

  - run: echo ${{steps.toLowerCase.outputs.lowerCaseValue}}
```

Comment: What about toUpperCase?

Comment: This is showing a blank output when I do the echo, why?

Comment: Unfortunately, the output is blank.

Comment: There MUST be semicolon before echo command INPUT=${{ env.UPPERCASE_VAR }}; echo .....

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to replace some chars in git version strings and was able to make a step like so:

```
  - name: prepare version string
    id: prep_version
    run: |
      export test_version=$(echo ${{ steps.tag_version.outputs.new_version }} |  sed 's/[^0-9,a-z,A-Z]/\-/g')
      echo ::set-output name=version::$test_version
```

that worked pretty good for me... so really we have anything that we could put on a cmd line

Answer (score 2):

I usually start by setting all global variables that I will use throughout the workflow.

```
jobs:
  variables: 
    outputs:
      tag_name: ${{ steps.var.outputs.tag_name}}
    runs-on: "ubuntu-latest"
    steps:
      - name: Setting global variables
        uses: actions/github-script@v6
        id: var
        with:
          script: |
            core.setOutput('tag_name', '${{ github.head_ref }}'.toLowerCase().replaceAll(/[/.]/g, '-').trim('-'));
```

Usage:

```yaml
  deploy:
    needs: [build, variables]
    runs-on: [ self-hosted, preview ]
    env:
      TAG_NAME: ${{ needs.variables.outputs.tag_name }}
    step:
      -name: Echo variables 
       run: |
         echo ${{ needs.variables.outputs.tag_name }}
         echo ${{ env.TAG_NAME}}
```

Answer (score 2):

After encountering some issues with the top voted answer, I found that it was not working (showing a blank string) because it only works inside the context. Here is the solution I found:

```
steps:
  - id: toLowerCase
    run: echo "::set-output name=lowerCaseValue::${UPPERCASE_VAR,,}"
    env:
      UPPERCASE_VAR: ${{ env.UPPERCASE_VAR }}

 - run: echo ${{steps.toLowerCase.outputs.lowerCaseValue}}
```

Here, we're defining the `UPPERCASE_VAR` environment variable as an input variable of the `toLowerCase` step. Then, in the run command, we're using the `${UPPERCASE_VAR,,}` syntax to convert the value of the variable to lowercase and assign it to the `lowerCaseValue` output variable. Finally, we're defining the `UPPERCASE_VAR` environment variable inside the step, so that it's available within the shell command.

Answer (score 0):

A new variant converting a string to lowercase without deprecated `set-output`.

A new operator `>>${GITHUB_OUTPUT}` is in use.

```yaml
env:
  VAR_UPPERCASE: "HELLO"

jobs:
  MyJob:
    steps:
    - name: Convert to lowercase
      id: convert2lowercase
      run: INPUT=${{ env.VAR_UPPERCASE }}; echo "VAR_LOWERCASE=${INPUT,,}">>${GITHUB_OUTPUT}
    - run: echo ${{steps.convert2lowercase.outputs.VAR_LOWERCASE}}
```